# Error while building OSMBright

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, osm2pgsql, cartocss

Error while building OSMBright

when i run the make.py

the following error is coming

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./make.py", line 123, in <module>
    build()
  File "./make.py", line 41, in build
    template = loads(templatefile.read())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 9 column 9 (char 304)
```

What i have done wrong

Answer (score 3):

Line 9 on your osm-bright.osm2pgsql.mml file, you left out a comma when adding the line "type": "shape",

You need to have proper JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

`Expecting , delimiter`

Do you have spaces where you should be using a comma on the command line call?

Comment: this make.py is given by OSMBright.. here i am new to all these. :(

Comment: Sounds more like the wrong delimiter is in some file (the template file?).